# diffrence between MyItemizedOverlay and OverLay in Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

what is the difference between `MyItemizedOverlay` and `OverLay` in Google Maps?
and can i use it together? where should i use each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlay is some kinda of layer for drawing. Overlay is more abstract then ItemizedOverlay.

ItemizedOverlay gives some helpfully methods for adding and managing some items on the  overlay layer (for example marks)

See javadoc:
[Overlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) and [ItemizedOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html)